# Sorting a 3D numpy array using numpy.argsort throws out a puzzling result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have the following array:

```
x = array([[[2, 5],
            [6, 7]],

           [[8, 1],
            [4, 9]]])
```

I want to sort it across the first column of each sub-arrays to get the following outcome:

```
out = array([[[2, 5],
              [6, 7]],

             [[4, 9],
              [8, 1]]])
```

So when run the following code:

```
x[:,x[:,:,0].argsort()]
```

the outcome is:

```
out1 = array([[[[2, 5],
                [6, 7]],

               [[6, 7],
                [2, 5]]],

              [[[8, 1],
                [4, 9]],

               [[4, 9],
                [8, 1]]]])
```

It turns out my desired outcome is on diagonal of this 2x2 matrix, so I can still get my desired outcome but I don't understand what the off-diagonals are. It doesn't even look like they are sorted in any way.

Where did the off-diagonal arrays come from?

Also, how can I get my desired outcome without having to go through this fairly large and useless array (`out1`)?

Comment: try with structured array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) instead of using slice:

```
x[np.arange(len(x))[:,None], x[...,0].argsort()]

#[[[2 5]
#  [6 7]]

# [[4 9]
#  [8 1]]]
```